# Non periodic orthonormal basis of $W^{1,2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm looking for different orthonormal basis of the space $W^{1,2}(0,1)$, i.e. the space of functions $L^2(0,1)$ with firth derivative also in $L^2(0,1)$. In particular I'm interested in a non periodic basis. Does someone know where I can find a sort of list of basis of $L^2$ or $W^{1,2}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057896/examples-of-orthonormal-bases-for-l20-1-that-are-not-trigonometric

Comment: "I'm interested in a non periodic basis": I don't see how that makes any sense. What does it even _mean_ to say that a function with domain $(0,1)$ is periodic?